# What's the origin of 'ditzy'?

Tags: etymology

The Online Etymology Dictionary said it was unknown. However, it also says that one of the meanings of [dis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dis&searchmode=none), as in *disrespect*, was originally:

> short for *disconnected* in the telephone sense and used figuratively in slang to mean "weak in the head"

I'm curious if *ditzy* may have come from *dis*.

Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I think it's more likely a corruption of the word dizzy

Comment: @MattE.Эллен -- [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dizzy+blonde%2C+ditzy+blonde&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdizzy%20blonde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cditzy%20blonde%3B%2Cc0) appears to support your theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Dr. William Long](http://www.drbilllong.com/SpellersDiary/InterludeII.html):

> .9. **Ditzy** (1973). It is hard to believe that this word is of such recent origin. It means "eccentrically silly, giddy, or insane," according to the *Collegiate*. The OED calls it *ditsy* and points to *dicty*, a word first appearing in 1926, as the progenitor of *ditsy*. But *dicty* means "conceited, high-class, snobbish." Though the OED says that the origin is unknown, it seems to have emerged in Black English, as reflected in this 1944 quotation: "These (*sic*) are only a few dozen words and phrases that are uniquely Negro...such as '*dicty*' which means trying to put on airs and act upper class without having the basis for doing so."
>
> Thus, I have a hard time seeing how *ditzy/ditsy* might have been derived from dicty. **In any case, once *ditzy* appeared on the scene in the late 1970s, it meant either "fussy"/"intricate" or, more frequently, "(Esp. of a woman) stupid, scatterbrained; cute."** Even though we were in the middle of the feminist revolution at that time, the word *ditzy* seemed to take on a meaning associating it exclusively with women. From a *Time* movie review in 1981: "Bob Newhart plays the President of the United States. Madeline Kahn is his ditso wife. Gilda Radner is their *ditsy* daughter." Perhaps receding images of Goldie Hawn also helped to give it an anit-feminist life of its own. **Or, perhaps when men felt threatened by the gradual incursions of feminist thought into the workplace, they retaliated by coining the term *ditzy*.**

---

Here's the OED's [1976](http://books.google.com/books?id=jysEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA64&dq=ditzy&hl=en&ei=20KtTouIKeeQ4gSe_NynDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA) earliest citation from *Texas Monthly*:

> After a day of shopping for school clothes or a prom dress, mother used to steer us to places like Neiman-Marcus' Zodiac Room (for Pot Luck Specials), Sakowitz's Sky Terrace (shrimp salad and cheese straws), Foley's Azalea Terrace (turkey mornay), or Frost Brothers' Tastesetter (margarita pie). Besides menus of **"ditzy ladies' things,"** these places had loads of cozy charm, an an occasional fashion show, and cheerful service.

Here's an antecedent from [1974](http://books.google.com/books?ei=20KtTouIKeeQ4gSe_NynDA&ct=result&id=rXBbAAAAMAAJ&dq=ditzy&q=ditzy#search_anchor)'s *Myra & Gore* by John Mitzel:

[image: And there she goes again, the ditzy queen, ...]

Here's another from a [1974](http://books.google.com/books?ei=w3CtTt3jOq3Q4QTn5KD1Dg&ct=result&id=mv8mAQAAIAAJ&q=ditzy#search_anchor) *New York Theatre Critics' Reviews*:

[image: The cast is headed by some grand old names — Alice Faye, who contributes a star's aura and a still splendid voice to the ditzy role of Professor Kenyon — the academic villain of the piece;]

Finally, here's an antecedent for the OED's alternate spelling *ditsy*, from [1973](http://www.google.com/search?q=ditsy&num=20&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=509&sa=X&ei=ImetToa2H63Q4QTn5KD1Dg&ved=0CBoQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1973,cd_max:1973&tbm=bks)'s *They've Shot the President's Daughter!* by Edward Stewart:

> I just couldn't keep my eyes off him, Fran, and I still can't believe he's interested in **ditsy little me!** But is he ever— oh boy! I practically had to pry him loose with a crowbar after the third "goodnight"! Anyway, wish me luck!

Comment: Likely [1972](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&btnmeta_news_search=1&q=%22ditsy%22+OR+%22ditzy%22&oq=%22ditsy%22+OR+%22ditzy%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=1628l8643l0l15630l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0#q=%22ditzy%22&hl=en&gl=us&sa=X&ei=YgwWT5y7IILe2AWumM2DCg&ved=0CBcQpwUoCw&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1972%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1972&tbm=nws&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1ca88e7427c11ef1&biw=1267&bih=705) appearance of _ditzy_. _Travels with Aunt_ was a '72 film.

Comment: @Callithumpian: Could well be. Although there's lots of *ditzy/dizzy* OCR errors...

Answer (score 2):

The OED says *origin unknown; perhaps corruption of 'dicty'*. *Dicty* means *snobbish, pretentious, self-important, ‘stuck-up’; having or characterized by aspirations to gentility or elegance; flashy, showy*.

First recorded use is in the 'Texas Monthly' in 1976.

Comment: I don't get how 'snobbish' and 'pretentious' can lead to 'stupid, scatterbrained'.

Comment: One of the meanings of ‘ditzy’ is ‘fussy, intricate’. It’s not a big step to that from ‘flashy, showy'. But, as the OED says, 'perhaps'. – Barrie England just now

Comment: Sounds more like 'glitzy' to me.

Answer (score 2):

The OED says for **ditsy** (the word can be spelled both ways) :

> (Esp. of a woman) stupid, scatterbrained; cute.

On the web, we can find a definition of *ditzy*   in the [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditzy), in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ditzy) and plenty of others.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ditzy) says "unknown origin" and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ditsy) says it could be a combination of *dotty* an *dizzy*.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the origin is similar to the recent PWNED term- an initial misspelling of "owned" that took on a life of its own. The 70's- where no spell check was available, this type of misprint wasn't uncommon. Seems the meaning is identical to "dizzy" when used in a sexist sense; "dizzy" is very close I spelling to "ditzy"- Just a theory

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dizzy+blonde%2C+ditzy+blonde&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdizzy%20blonde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cditzy%20blonde%3B%2Cc0) sort of supports this -- "dizzy blonde" goes back to about 1900 and really took off in the 30s.  And, after sliding in the 60s and recovering in the 70s and 80s, it began to slide again just as "ditzy blonde" took off.  This would explain why so many of us remember it being older.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "ditzy" is an adjective stemming from the name "Gerda Ditzen" circa 1929, who was described in the December 2015 issue of "Discover" magazine by James S. Forrester in his article "Crazy Heart" as "so thoroughly smitten that she seemed bereft of all judgement."   Interestingly, Ms. Ditzen's actions were essential for Dr. Werner Forssmann to perform a bold experiment on himself and earn a Nobel Prize in Medicine.

Answer (score -4):

I think it came from DIDS.. Damsel in Distress~

Comment: Do you have a citation from an authority? This site strongly prefers answers which provided referenced explanations.