# Meaning of “a dizzard”

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation, dialects, literary-english, dialectal

I’m working on translation of an American novel, dating back to the late 19th - early 20th centuries, and the main character came from a local little Vermont town.

The author describes him as “old dizzard” (“… the old dizzard had been for years the local butt”).

- I can’t find out the meaning of “dizzard” by myself, so would you please help me?
- Could it be a sort of a dialect (because I’ve already come across dialectical quotes within this novel)?

Comment: The definition of “dizzard” is present in all main dictionaries.

Comment: The word _dizzard_ is not mentioned in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) or in _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010)—the two main hard-copy dictionaries that people in the United States are likeliest to own. I don't think it's unreasonable, under the circumstances, to ask about its meaning at this site.

Comment: it isn't in my oxford compact dictionary either (it is compact at only 1212 pages)

Answer (score 10):

From Robert Nares, James Halliwell & Thomas Wright, [*A Glossary or, Collection of Words, Phrases, Names, and Allusions to Customs, Proverbs, Etc., Which Have Been Thought to Require Illustration*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m2sCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA246&dq=%22dizzard%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_jM7Vv5j9AhXjPn0KHQ65BvwQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22dizzard%22&f=false) (1859):

> A **DIZARD**, **DIZZARD**, or **DISARD**. A blockhead, or fool. Probably from the same Saxon etymology as dizzy, *dysi*. Some have said, from *disard*, Fr. for a prater, or babbling fellow ; but no such word was ever used in French. Their word is *diseur* ; nor does the English word mean so much a prater, as a downright dunce, or fool. Thus Cotgrave renders it, not by *diseur*, or any such word, but by *lourdaut*.
>
> > He that cannot personate the wise man well amongst wisards, let him learn to play the fool well amongst *dizzards*. *G. Chapm., Masque of the Middle Temple*, C1.
> >
> > What a revengeful *dizard* is this! *Lingua*, O. P1, v, 165.
> >
> > Whereat the sergeant wroth, said, *Dizzard*, calfe, / Thou woud'st if thou hadst wit or sense to see. *Harringt., Ep.*, 2, 9.
>
> {In the old English Homer by Art. Hall (1581), p. 10, which was translated from the French, we have:}
>
> > You hereaulter high, come on, quoth he, no daunger dread at all, / For by your *disarde* king, not you, their wrong on me doth fall.
>
> {The *dizard* was properly the vice, or fool, in a play ; the jester. This would seem to justify the Fr. derivation.}
>
> > [Latin quotation omitted] A *dizzard* or common vice and jester, counterfetting the gestures of any man, and moving his body as him list. *Nomenclator*.

Comment: This is just wonderful!

Comment: I had suspected that "dizzard" was related to the modern "ditzy"; though [the etymology of "ditzy" is also uncertain](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46715/whats-the-origin-of-ditzy), some etymologists have suggested that it also comes from "dizzy," in which case the two would seem to be connected etymologically.

Comment: I really like the coupling with wizard in the cite.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a bigger dictionary. :) [OED says a *dizzard* is](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/56211):

> 1. = **disour** n.; a jester, a ‘fool’.
>    2. A foolish fellow, idiot, blockhead.

The spelling can vary. Here are two of their citations:

> - 1817   I. D'Israeli *Curiosities of Lit.* 1st Ser. III. 352 
>     One may be as great a dizzard in resolving a problem as in restoring a reading.
> - 1886   M. K. Macmillan *Dagonet the Jester* ii. 100  
>    They flattered the wantonness of young lords and old wealthy disards.

For its etymology, they give:

> **Etymology**: First found c1520. Perhaps a modification of earlier *disour* n., by assimilation to words in -*ard* suffix. See the intermediate forms in -*er* , -*are* , -*ar* in sense 1. In later use, esp. in sense 2, apparently associated with *dizzy* adj.

Answer (score 1):

[The Free Dictionary defines "dizzard" as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dizzard)

> *(obsolete)* a dunce, an idiot

Given the age of the book, the use of an "obsolete" term is hardly surprising.

Comment: If you think the late 19th and early 20th centuries makes something liable to be "obsolete", then you need to live a little bit. :)

Comment: You don't understand, @tchrist. It's not that the book is from the late 19th or early 20th century that makes it "obsolete". It's that it's *a book*. :-)